# How do you show that the cyclic group $C_4$ is a subgroup of the Quaternion group?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups, quaternions

> How do you show that the cyclic group $C_4$ is a subgroup of the Quaternion group?

Obviously the cyclic group $C_4$ is a subgroup of $Q_8$ but I was wondering how do you show this?

Comment: You exhibit an element of order $4$ in $Q_8$.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: You shouldn't say "Obviously" if you then do not have a proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number $i$ has order four in $Q_8$, since $i=i, i^2=-1, i^3=-i,$ and $i^4=(-1)^2=1$,  so $C_4\cong\langle i\rangle,$ the subgroup generated by $i$.

*NB:* The group $C_4$ is *isomorphic* to a subgroup of $Q_8$, not *equal to* a subgroup.